# Autofill function in Laravel AJAX does not appear or auto fill the other inputs

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form. This form takes 1 input as an id which is email. Other 2 inputs are `nama` and `kelas`. Those are decided based on the email input. So if I select an email, the other 2 inputs will be auto filled or appear. But somehow my function does not auto fill the those inputs. It should be if I select an email, then the `nama` and `kelas` get auto filled / appear on the input field.

This is the view (create.blade.php). The script for jquery is included inside my template file which the jquery is `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

```
@extends('template')
@section('content')
<meta name="_token" content="{{csrf_token()}}" />
<div id="bk">
    <h2>Tambah Bobot dan Kriteria</h2>
    <form action="{{url('/datacalon/submit')}}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Email Calon Pengurus OSIS</label>
          <select name="email" id = "email" onblur="autofill()" class="form-control">
            <option disabled selected> -- email calon pengurus osis -- </option>
            @foreach ($columns as $c)
              <option value="{{ $c->email }}" id = "email" onblur="autofill()" >{{ $c->email }}</option>
            @endforeach
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nama Calon Pengurus OSIS</label>
            <input type="text" name="nama" id="nama" class="form-control" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Kelas Calon Pengurus OSIS</label>
            <input type="text" name="kelas" id="kelas" class="form-control" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
            function autofill(){
                var email = $("#email").val();
                $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });
                
                $.ajax({
                url: '/getPengurusOsis/' + email,
                method: "get",
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(response) {
                     $("#nama").val(response.nama)
                    $("#kelas").val(response.kelas)
                    }
                });
            }
</script>
@endsection
```

This is the route (web.php)

```
Route::get('/datacalon', 'DatacalonController@index');
Route::get('/datacalon/create', 'DatacalonController@create');
Route::get('/getPengurusOsis/{email}', 'DatacalonController@getCalonPengurusOsis');
```

This is the controller (DataCalonController.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class DatacalonController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
    $halaman = 'datacalon';
    // $columns = DB::table('bobotkriteria')->select('nama')->get();
    $columns = DB::table('bobotkriteria')->get();
    return view('datacalon.index',['columns' => $columns]);
    }

    public function create(Request $req){
        $columns = DB::table('users')->get();
        return view('datacalon.create',['columns' => $columns]);
    }

    public function getCalonPengurusOsis($email){
        $columns = DB::table('users')->where('email',$email)->first();
        return response()->json([
           'nama' => $columns->nama,
           'kelas' => $columns->kelas
        ]);
    }
}
```

What did I miss from the code? Please help

Comment: jQuery'a slim version doesn't contain the Ajax module. From the [download page](https://jquery.com/download/): _"You can also use the slim build, which excludes the ajax and effects modules:"_

Comment: oh okay, I have changed it to min.js. It works but somehow I should click anywhere of the page to auto fill it, thanks @MagnusEriksson. I have changed it into onclick